# How to call an element in an 2D python array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to change the value of a certain element in a 2D array.
the 2D array is a num1 by num2 matrix with every element as 0. I'm trying to change the `Rth`
row `Cth` column of the matrix to 1

```
matrix = []
def make_matrix(num1, num2):
    row = []
    for i in range(num1):
        row.append(0)
    for i in range(num2):
        matrix.append(row)

def change_to_one(R, C):
    matrix[R-1][C-1] = 1

make_matrix(3, 2)
change_to_one(2, 1)
print(matrix)
```

it prints `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]` instead of `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`

Comment: `matrix = [[0] * 3 for i in range(2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with pointers.
You first define `row=[]`
When you do this `matrix.append(row)` `num2` times, you are appending the address of `row`, hence if you change `row` anytime, it will be broadcasted subsequently.

In other words, changing data in `row` will change data everywhere you appended `row` to which in your case is all `rows` of 2D matrix.

Try this code:

```
def make_matrix(num1, num2):
    for i in range(num2):
      row = []
      for i in range(num1):
          row.append(0)
      matrix.append(row)
```

Here we create a new `row` everytime and then append it to our matrix, this way changes in any `row` will not be broadcasted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

- You are using a reference to the original list when you do `matrix.append(row[:])`. This can be circumvented by just copying the elements of the list as `row[:]` instead of using `row`. Otherwise, whatever changes you do to the first row, will also be reflected in all the other rows.
- You forgot to return after modifying the matrix. **This is not a major problem in your case as the scope of your `matrix` is global**.

---

```
matrix = []

def make_matrix(num1, num2):
    row = []
    for i in range(num1):
        row.append(0)
    for i in range(num2):
        matrix.append(row[:]) # <--- Use row[:] instead of row

def change_to_one(R, C):
    matrix[R-1][C-1] = 1
    return matrix # <---- return from here 

make_matrix(3, 2)
matrix = change_to_one(2, 1) # <---- save the returned result in a variable 
print(matrix)

# [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: `matrix` in the function is used as a "global" variable. It seems to work even without the `return`, correct?

Comment: @Dino: You are right. Here it will work without return too, which is in general, not a good practice. I will add your point to my answer though